# How Can I Convert this Lua Code to be Able to be Used in Older Version? (What is the Order of Precedence of Lua Bitwise Operators?)

Tags: lua, base64, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have this Lua code in Lua 5.3 for Base64:

```lua
local bs = { [0] =
   'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P',
   'Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f',
   'g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v',
   'w','x','y','z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','+','/',
}

local function base64(s)
   local byte, rep = string.byte, string.rep
   local pad = 2 - ((#s-1) % 3)
   s = (s..rep('\0', pad)):gsub("...", function(cs)
      local a, b, c = byte(cs, 1, 3)
      return bs[a>>2] .. bs[(a&3)<<4|b>>4] .. bs[(b&15)<<2|c>>6] .. bs[c&63]
   end)
   return s:sub(1, #s-pad) .. rep('=', pad)
end
```

I wanted to use it in older versions, but the problem is it does have the bitwise operators (not library). I can easily replace the symbols to the corresponding functions, but I don't know the precedence of Lua bitwise operators.

Comment: "I don't know the precedence of Lua bitwise operators." Why not? It's clearly documented in the manual: [3.4.8 – Precedence](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.8)